# How to convert a pandas series into a numericals only series?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas series which contains float, integer and alphanumerical elements. The float and integer elements are also of type string like below:-

```
sr = pd.Series(['80', '25.1', '08!shashi123', '2!shekhar45@!#', '6.23'])
```

I want to convert this series into just a numerical series like below and replace the alphanumerical elements with a `NaN` like below:-

```
sr = pd.Series([80, 25.1, 'NaN', 'NaN', 6.23])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [to_numeric](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with error coercion:

```
import pandas as pd

sr = pd.Series(['80', '25.1', '08!shashi123', '2!shekhar45@!#', '6.23'])

result = pd.to_numeric(sr, errors='coerce')

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
0    80.00
1    25.10
2      NaN
3      NaN
4     6.23
dtype: float64
```